# Why doesn’t my second override of viewDidLoad get called?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I override viewDidLoad twice. The second time, so I can set a delegate. Yet...it is not being called because myDel is nil. Why isn't my override, in the concrete class CoolTableController getting called?

```
protocol CoolTableProtocol {
   //unrelevant code
}

class CoolTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var myDel: CoolProtocol!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("myDel")
        //this should not be nil....yet it is
        print(myDel)
    }
}

class CoolTableController: CoolTableViewController,CoolTableProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.myDel = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And the way I call this is:

```
let coolTableVC = CoolTableController()
mainView.addSubview(coolTableVC.view)
self.addChild(coolTableVC)
coolTableVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Kindly check updated answer hope it helps

Comment: the 2nd viewDidLoad isn't being called because your "view" is nil. You have to initialize your view controller in any of these ways. 
1. Load from xib
2. Load from storyboard
3. programmatically create a view controller having a view with a specified frame

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `ViewDidLoad` is a life cycle function and it will not get triggered programmatically and only triggered when

> - viewDidLoad Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.

Creating a plain instance of the `UIViewController` will not trigger those functions by it self.

So you can call `coolTableVC.view` like this `let _ = coolTableVC.view` as the function will trigger after `.view` is loaded.

Comment: also incorrect. youll see the two print statements...are getting called by myDel is nil because only ONE of the overrides is getting called

Comment: i dont understand the answer. Maybe you can provide more a little bit more explanation about why you believe it works? Also the variable named _ is extremely confusing, maybe replace it with a descriptive name?

Comment: you don't need to use it you're just calling it to trigger did load, apple documentation says that view did load called after the vc view is loaded so calming it will load it to memory, give it a try call the variable then debug your view controller